# Scala XML parse multiple fields

Tags: xml, scala

I have an XML document structured like:

```
<document>
  <Imposed_TimeSeries>
  ...
  </Imposed_TimeSeries>

  <Confirmed_TimeSeries>
  ...
  </Confirmed_TimeSeries>
</document>
```

I would like to get a `NodeSeq` of all `TimeSeries` elements with a filter like: `(document \ "*_TimeSeries")`. Is there any (easy) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
    val result: NodeSeq = (xml \ "_").filter(_.label.contains("TimeSeries"))
```

Look at the source of  `\` :

> this \ "_" to get a list of all child elements (wildcard);

But you need `\\` to access your different `TimeSeries`

```
println(result \\ "Confirmed_TimeSeries")
println(result \\ "Imposed_TimeSeries")
```